# how do I query sql for a Sum value + latest record date

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have students table and i need to collect the value by calculating the formula.

```
Date,Person name,status,value,mark1,mark2
01/08/2020,Andrew,New,10,32,45
07/08/2020,Andrew,New,10,44,44
22/08/2020,Andrew,New,10,55,34
15/09/2020,Mirandz,New,11,44,44
22/09/2020,Mirandz,New,11,77,55
07/09/2020,Lucaz,New,54,66,55
30/09/2020,Lucaz,New,54,23,55
```

here i would like to do `sum(mark1)+sum(mark2)+value(where date is maximum) based on Person name`

Need help on write the SQL Query to get the summarized value for latest value add with existing column values.

```
32+44+55+45+44+34+10
```

I tried with below query

```
Select SUM(mark1)+SUM(Mark2)+Value from table where MAX(date)
```

am totally new to sql server! any help will much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values are constant in your sample data per name, so you can use:

```
select name, sum(mark1) + sum(mark2) + value
from students
group by name, value;
```

If the value were not constant, you could implement the logic in a variety of ways.  One uses `first_value()`:

```
select name, sum(mark1) + sum(mark2) + most_recent_value
from (select s.*,
             first_value(value) over (partition by name order by date desc) as most_recent_value
      from students s
     ) s
group by name, most_recent_value;
```